# Why does Swift playground shows wrong number of executions?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am using a completion handler to sum up numbers. What I don't understand is if I break my code in 2 lines, the number of executions would change from 6 to 7!! WHY?

```
 func summer (from : Int, to: Int, handler: (Int) -> (Int)) -> Int {
        var sum = 0
        for i in from...to {
            sum += handler(i)
        }
        return sum

}

summer(1, to:6){ //Shows '21'
    return $0} // shows '(6 times)'


// Same code, but in 1 line
summer(1, to:6){return $0} // shows '(7 times)'
```

**IMAGE**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's showing how many times a function / expression is being called on that line:

[image]

since the calling expression (summer()) is on the same line, it counts as an extra operation. Hence, 6 prints + 6 returns + 1 summer() = 13 times something happened on that line.

I'm sure I'm not using the correct terminology, but this is what's going on.

Comment: It's not showing the number of closure expressions.. It's showing the number of expressions expressed in the closure ^-^() Unless I'm mistaken on something here...

Answer (score 4):

It's merely a consequence of the presentation:

```
21 //the result from the first time
(6 times) //the other 6 times

(7times) //all 7 times, including the 21 one.
```

Comment: What exactly is being counted here?

Comment: The number of executions of the closure. The first of those executions returned `21`

Comment: So in the 2 line version, instead of letting us know of the '1 time' execution it would just pop the result ie 21?

Comment: Yeah, if a piece of code only runs once, it'll give you the actual value instead of the number of times it ran.